# How to update(add/remove) all Groups in ONE Grouping, without affecting OTHER Groupings?

Tags: api, mailchimp

I need help with an API call to update a Members Groups in a Grouping in my MailChimp List.

I have a few "Interest Groupings", each with several "Groups". For example, the first two are....
Grouping: Purchased
Groups: P_SPA3ASX, P_SPA3CFD, P_SPA3ETF, .....

Grouping: Member Stattus
Groups: Lead, Active, Inactive, Staff

Using an API call, I would like to update the Groups in the Purchased Grouping, without affecting ANY of the other Groupings. I have had some success but one scenario eludes me.

My API Call looks like this:
POST to: https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/update-member.json
POST Body is:

```
{
    "apikey": "myapikey",
    "id": "mtlistid",
    "email": {
        "leid": "165320973"
    },
    "double_optin": false,
    "update_existing": false,
    "send_welcome": false,
    "replace_interests": false,
    "merge_vars": {
        "groupings": [
            {
                "name": "Purchased",
                "groups": ["P_SPA3ASX","","","",""]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I change the "replace_interests" setting and pass different "groups" to the API, this is what happens.

Scenario 1: replace_interests = false
Result:
Good. Groups are added to "Purchased".
Bad. Groups are NOT removed from "Purchased".
Good. Other Groupings are not affected.

Scenario 2: replace_interests = true
Result:
Good. Groups are added to "Purchased".
Good. Groups are removed from "Purchased".
Bad. Other Groupings ARE affected. They are all cleared!

But how do I achieve all three (Add Groups, Remove Groups and Not affect other Groupings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible via API v2.0. In order to update a list subscribers interests, you have to supply all of them due to the use of an array to describe that data. In API v3.0, interests can be modified individually without affecting other interests.

Comment: Thanks. That forced me to move to API version 3, which requires a few extra hoops to jump through but I have the basic updates working via calls from Hurl.it. I found that Ver 3 works more with IDs, rather than names which makes the migration of existing code a bit harder in some respects but overall I see the moves as beneficial.  For everyone's Info: Groups and Groupings are now called Interest Categories and Interests in Version 3...much clearer!